# Get method type of previous url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest, http-referer

I want to get the method type (POST and PUT) of previous URL in Laravel.

For ex.
I have used Resource routes. So let's assume there are 2 pages Create Product and Edit Product. Both pages contains a form. Once that form is submitted to respected routes (store and update), it calls to index action of Product. So now what I am looking for is to get the method type of previous URL. That means `POST` for store route and `PUT` for update route on listing action of Controller.

I tried several ways like
`url()->previous()`
`app('router')->getRoutes()->match(app('request')->create(url()->previous(), 'PUT'))->getName()`
and many more but none of them worked for me.

**Note: I am developing a package so can't rely on any action of controller. By default index action calls to the package so I want to get this thing in my class.**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If I read the source code correct, only GET requests are stored in the session:     https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/689b17242650a9af9f57b166f0df6f5bf5b35ee5/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L200

Comment: @RolandStarke Yes, Any idea how to get other types?

Comment: You mean you submit a form and then directly call index method at the end of store and update method? So, You arent using redirect to previous url or redirect route?

Comment: @DeepeshThapa I've redirected to index action at the end of store and update method using `redirect()->route('admin.products.index')`

Comment: I dont think you can really get previous method that way. All I can suggest is to send an optional parameter on your index method. so on your route you can make the parameter optional using `index/{?method}` . Then on your index method use `public function index($method=null) `

Comment: Continue to previous comment : And then you can redirect to route using `redirect()->route('admin.products.index',["method"=>"POST"])`

Comment: @DeepeshThapa Yes, I can do that way but as I already mentioned in question that I'm developing  package so I can't do anything on controller. Following your way needs to change all the controllers.

Answer (score -2):

### You can pass parameter containing information to your index route, LIKE

> Let's consider /products as an index route,

> you can pass /products?ref_type=POST or /products?ref_type=PUT while redirecting from your CREATE or UPDATE form.

> and in your controller, you can get that param like, $request->ref_type or $request['ref_type']

> For get request, it will give null so can easily differentiate between the type of requests

Comment: I can do this way but as I already mentioned in question that I'm developing a package so I can't do anything on controller side.

Comment: @YashParekh, you can get your variables in blade too as `$_GET'ref_type']`, if you don't want to interact with the controller.